# Как сделать что бы не вылетало?

Tags: java, android, аудио

Написал простое приложение Ехо звука. Проблема в том что при переходе в другие приложения звук отключается. Но например в Zello все работает.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static AudioRecord audio;
    public static AudioTrack audioTrack;

    static final String TAG = "SoundRecorder";
    static final int RECORDING_RATE = 8000; // can go up to 44K, if needed
    static final int CHANNEL_IN = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    static final int CHANNELS_OUT = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    static final int FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT;
    public static int BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDING_RATE, CHANNEL_IN, FORMAT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDING_RATE,CHANNEL_IN,FORMAT,BUFFER_SIZE);  
        audio.startRecording();

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, MainActivity.RECORDING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT , MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.play();
        new myThread().start();
    }    
}
```

---

```
class myThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        byte[] b = new byte[MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE];

        for(;;){
            MainActivity.audio.read(b,0,MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);
            MainActivity.audioTrack.write(b,0,MainActivity.BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Почему не корректно отображается код?

Comment: Чтоб не вылетало? :D оберните весь код в `try{ } catch(Exception e){}`

Comment: Ну а если серьезно то для того чтобы музыка играла в фоне, нужен сервис. А просто так сервисы долго не живут, у сервиса должно быть уведомление, запущенное через `startForeground`.

Comment: работайте через сервисы и никогда не запускайте java треды в ui потоке. У андроида множество инструментов для многопоточной работы

Comment: Попробуйте присваивать Thread в поле класса, а не анонимно. А также перенести в поток ВЕСЬ код с аудио, а не только тот цикл.